# Can partition be done in informatica if the source is data base?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange

Can we apply partition in informatica if the source is orcale?

How can we do that in informatica power center?

My session is getting failed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes partition can be added even when the source is Oracle. In Informatica Workflow Manager, in mapping tab select partition tab. Over there you can find the transformations to add partition on. Select a transformation and click on Add Partition.